# How can I turn off quick look on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: catalina

On Mac if you select a file and press the space bar on your keyboard, you can see a quick look of the file.

Is there any way to disable this feature on Mac?

Is there a terminal command or a system tool that can disable Quick-Look on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo launchctl unload -w com.apple.quicklook.plist
```

I don't know whether you will have to disable SIP to do this, or even if it's possible since Catalina [& can't test].

Found on Apple Forums - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2582860